# Combining dates in multiple cells into 1 cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have the following dates in 3 columns (M, D, Y) on my spreadsheet. 
How do I get the dates into 1 column?

```
SEP 16, 2015,
FEB 29, 2016,
FEB 4,  2016
```

Answer (score 0):

You state 1 column in your question, but 1 cell in your title.

Assuming 1 cell is what you want, you can either use the `CONCATENATE` function, or use `&` between cells and strings to put them together.

For example:

```
=A1&", "&B1&", "&C1
```

[image]

Edit: Updated following comment:

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the title. My mistake. I do want the date to be in one cell.

Comment: Using your example, Sep would be column A, 16 in column B, and 2015 in column C. I need the date of Sep 16, 2015 to be in one cell.

Comment: Okay. Exactly the same formula then :)

Comment: @Nemesis See added screenshot, amend the commas as required, looks like you may not need the one between A1 and B1.

Comment: That worked! Thanks VERY much. I notice now however that I am unable to change the date format. That's a new one. I want the date to be in the mm/dd/yy format, but it won't convert. Any thoughts on that one?

Comment: OK, I got that one myself. I preceded your formula with the DateValue function, and now all is well in my world. Thank you again for your time and help.

Comment: For anyone interested, the final formula looks like this: =datevalue(A1&" "&B1&" "&C1).

Comment: + You may do the same as custom formatting in the "format cell" (CTRL+1) dialog using e.g. `=TEXT(datevalue(...),"YY-MM-DD")`